# how to read (or parse) EXCEL comments using python

Tags: python, excel

I have several excel files that use lots of comments for saving information.
For example, one cell has value 2 and there is a comment attached to the cell saying 
"2008:2#2009:4". it seems that value 2 is for the current year (2010) value. The comment keeps all previous year values separated by '#'. I would like to create a dictionary to keep all this info like {2008:2, 2009:4, 2010:2} but I don't know how to parse (or read) this comment attached to the cell. Python excel readin module has this function (reading in comment)?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without an Excel COM object using `openpyxl`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook('/tmp/data.xlsx')
first_sheet = workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)

for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.comment:
            print(cell.comment.text)
```

The parsing of the comments itself can be done the same as with Steven Rumbalski's answer.

(example adapted from [here](https://gist.github.com/yosemitebandit/2869767))

Comment: openpyxl doesnot support xls files...Is there any other way to read comments from xls files? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Normally for reading from Excel, I would suggest using xlrd, but xlrd does not support comments.  So instead use the Excel COM object:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("Book1.xls")
sh = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
comment = sh.Cells(1,1).Comment.Text()
```

And here's how to parse the comment:

```
comment = "2008:2#2009:4"
d = {}
for item in comment.split('#'):
    key, val = item.split(':')
    d[key] = val
```

Often, Excel comments are on two lines with the first line noting who created the comment.  If so your code would look more like this:

```
comment = """Steven:
2008:2#2009:4"""
_, comment = comment.split('\n')
d = {}
for item in comment.split('#'):
    key, val = item.split(':')
    d[key] = val
```

Comment: This is surprisingly clean. The only problem is that it requires you to have Excel installed. Is there a way to do this with LibreOffice?  Bonus points if it works on Linux.

Comment: Does it have to iterate cell by cell? Can it extract all the comments from a column? Thanks @Steven Rumbalski

Answer (score 0):

After running the last posted code here, can you store that information later in a word document?

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
    
workbook = load_workbook('/tmp/data.xlsx')
first_sheet = workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)

for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.comment:
            print(cell.comment.text)
```